# Problem with two preg_match-functions one after another

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, str-replace

i have a variable `$cart_item` that contains the code of a template I want to include on my page.

As this template has some information I don't need necessarily, I use the function `preg_match` to find and `str_replace` to delete these information from `$cart_item`.
The first time I use `preg_match` this is working fine. But the second time I want to use it, it doesn't find any matches.

The code:

```
        preg_match("/(<if type>)(.+?)(<\/if>)/s", $cart_item, $matches);
        if($item['type'] != "") {
            $cart_item = str_replace($matches[1], "", $cart_item);
            $cart_item = str_replace($matches[3], "", $cart_item);
            $cart_item = str_replace("{{item_type}}", $item['type'], $cart_item);
        } else {
            $cart_item = str_replace($matches[0], "", $cart_item);
        }

        preg_match("/(<if campaign_codes>)(.+?)(<\/if>)/s", $cart_item, $matches);

        var_dump($matches);

        if($item['campaign_codes'] != "") {
        } else {
            echo "Keine Kampagnen vorhanden";
            $cart_item = str_replace($matches[0], "", $cart_item);
        }
```

Until the end of the first if-clause, everything works fine. But after I call the next `preg_match` and after that `var_dump($matches)`, the array is empty.

Now the trick: if I leave out the first if-clause, the array isn't empty after the first execution of `preg_match`.

I already tried renaming the array of the second `preg_match`, but that doesn't help.

I don't know how, but the first if-clause seems to do anything it shouldn't.

Anybody could explain it to me and give me an advice how to solve the problem?

Comment: How do you know if `preg_match("/(<if type>)(.+?)(<\/if>)/s", $cart_item, $matches);` actually matched something ? Also, you're deleting the first match items, so maybe there are none left to match on the second preg_match().

Comment: See this answer for a better way to approach this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702506/how-to-preg-replace-all-in-the-large-amount-of-data

Comment: @Maxt8r I know, because the if-clause is working. In this situation, `$item['type']` is "", so the else-clause is executed.
And to your second note: I don't see the problem here. The second `preg_match` is using a different pattern, so why does that matter?

Comment: @Maxt8r I don't see the similarities to the linked solution. I'm trying something different, as I make the replacements depending on some further information given in my `$item`-array.
So the problem for me still is, what impact the first if-clause has on the second `preg_match`function. Without the first if-clause, it's working.

Comment: Between the two `preg_match()`, $cart_item is modified to delete the things the first preg_match found. Since the second `preg_match()` tries to match the same thing that has been deleted, it doesn't find it.

Comment: But why should the second `preg_match` try to match the same thing that has been deleted? The patterns are different - the first `preg_match` tries to find "<if type>" and the second tries to find <if campaign_codes>. And as the first if-clause is working correctly, the "<if campaign_codes>"-part is not deleted and still existing for the second `preg_match`.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62782267/edit) and add the content of `$cart_item` and `$item` or, at least, an extract thatt allow us to test.

Answer (score 0):

> And as the first if-clause is working correctly, the "<if campaign_codes>"-part is not deleted and still existing for the second `preg_match`.

You overlook that [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) replaces *all occurrences of the search string*, so the `str_replace($matches[3], "", $cart_item)` where `$matches[3]` is `"</if>"` also removes the end tag of *the "<if campaign_codes>"-part* which consequently isn't matched thereafter.

> an advice how to solve the problem?

You could use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to delete exactly the found matches and nothing else:

```
        preg_match("/(<if type>)(.+?)(<\/if>)/s", $cart_item, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        if ($item['type'] != "") {
            $cart_item = substr_replace($cart_item, "", $matches[3][1], strlen($matches[3][0]));
            $cart_item = str_replace("{{item_type}}", $item['type'], $cart_item);
            $cart_item = substr_replace($cart_item, "", $matches[1][1], strlen($matches[1][0]));
        } else {
            $cart_item = substr_replace($cart_item, "", $matches[0][1], strlen($matches[0][0]));
        }
```

Note that the removals have to be done in order from back to front since they change the positions of following string parts.